# Difference between On-heap and Off-heap memory

Tags: memory, jvm, off-heap

Can someone explain the difference between on-heap memory and off-heap memory?Does the off-heap memory show on the JVM memory size?Are the off-heap all pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All memory is native memory, however the JVM manages and record memory in it's JVM heap (not the same as the native heap)

Offheap is a Java term for memory not managed directly.  However, it can be managed indirectly using direct ByteBuffer(s) as proxy objects for raw native memory.

Comment: What does "not managed directly" mean?Does this mean that kind of object  is not managed by the JVM?Is that just a pointer in JVM?

Comment: @XiaolongZhou it's just a 64-bit `long` value which happens to be the address of some memory.

Comment: Does the memory occupy the JVM memory?Or just the 64-bit long value is in the JVM, the pointed object is out of the range of JVM?Thanks!

Comment: @XiaolongZhou off heap memory is still part of the memory of the process so from the OS point of view it is no different however it is not part of the normal areas the JVM uses.